# Fade in and out series of images but only show a few at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I'm trying to figure out how to make this trick work.

I have a series of images:

```
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" alt="">
</div>
```

And what I want to do is make them fade in and out, but only show a max of five at a time and then have them randomly fade in and out between each of them.

I know if I add this:

```
.images img:nth-child(n+5) {
    display: none;
}
```

This will hide the rest of the images, but I can't really figure out how to go about getting the other to fade in and the other to fade out.

Not sure if there is a something like jQuery Cycle2 that can handle that or of there is something else that can try and "cycle" through the other images that are hidden and just keep going through.

Answer (score 1):

I created a quick, simple jQuery function that might get you started. The function essentially takes two arguments (both classnames). The function takes all the images that have the classname set in the first argument, and gets one random image with that classname. It then removes that class from the image, and adds the class in the second argument.

Because I've defined two css classes, `hide` and `show`, I can use my function to hide a random image that's currently showing, then display another random image that's currently hidden.

The functions are set to a timer and will run every 600ms.

```js
function shuffleRandomCat(remove, add) {
  const cats = $("."+remove).toArray();
  const catLength = cats.length;
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*catLength);
  const randomCat = cats[randomNum];
  $(randomCat).removeClass(remove);
  $(randomCat).addClass(add);
}

window.setInterval(function(){
  // remove a cat
  shuffleRandomCat("show", "hide");
  // display a cat
  shuffleRandomCat("hide", "show");
}, 600);
```

```css
img {
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
  border: 2px solid black;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  width: auto;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="images">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" class="show">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" class="show">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" class="show">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" class="show">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" class="show">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/600" class="hide">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/700" class="hide">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/800" class="hide">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/900/900" class="hide">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/700" class="hide">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/600" class="hide">
</div>
```

Comment: This works pretty well, thanks! But the one question that I have is this: `const cats = $("."+remove).toArray();` Does that target _everything_? And if I just wanted to target the images within the class of `.images` could I change that to be `const cats = $(".images img"+remove).toArray();`?

Comment: @ultraloveninja `const cats = $("."+remove).toArray();` is targeting whatever class I passed to the function as the `remove` argument. So, if I call the function like `shuffleRandomCat("show", "hide");`, then the line will be `const cats = $(".show").toArray();` (only targets elements with `show` class). If you only want to target images with the `image` class, you could just call the function passing in the `image` class: `shuffleRandomCat("images", "hide");`. Hope that makes sense, feel free to message me if you need more help understanding the logic.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhm ok. Cool. That make sense. Yeah, I was messing with it a bit and I had added and addition bit of JS to apply the `show` class to the first 5 elements and then add `hide` to the rest. But either way, that method should still work. Thanks again!

Comment: @ultraloveninja You're very welcome! If you found this solution useful, please mark it as the accepted answer :)